# Christoffel symbols in exact plane waves

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, curvature

In the book "A first course of General Relativity" by Schutz I am stuck in trying to calculate Christoffel's symbols for an exact plane wave. I have the metric:
$$ds^2 = -dudv+f^2(u)dx^2+g^2(u)dy^2$$
from which I think I get $g_{uv}=g_{vu}=-1/2$ , $g_{xx}=f^2(u)$ and $g_{yy}=g^2(u)$.

So, in order to calculate $\Gamma^x_{xu}$ and$\ \Gamma^x_{xu}$ , I thought to use the formula $\Gamma^k_{li}=\frac{1}{2}g^{jm}(\frac{\partial g_{ij}}{\partial q^l}+\frac{\partial g_{lj}}{\partial q^i}-\frac{\partial g_{il}}{\partial q^j})$ .

So I get   $\ \ \Gamma^x_{xu} = \frac{1}{2} g^{xx}2\dot{f}(u)/f(u)=\frac{\dot{f}(u)}{f(u)}$ which is equal to the result of the book.
Though, when calculating in this way $\Gamma^v_{xx}$ what I get is $\frac{1}{2} g^{uv}(-2\dot{f}(u)f(u))=2\dot{f(u)}f(u)$. The problem is that the correct answer would be $2\frac{\dot{f}(u)}{f(u)}$. Where have I gone wrong here?

EDIT:

Schutz's book also reports the value of $R^x_{uxu} = -\frac{\ddot{f}}{f}$ . Calculating it through the formula : $R^{\alpha}_{\beta \mu \nu}=\frac{1}{2} g ^{\alpha \sigma}(g_{\sigma \nu , \beta \mu} - g_{\sigma \mu , \beta \nu }+g_{\beta \mu , \sigma \nu}-g_{\beta \nu , \sigma \mu})$
I get $R^x_{uxu} = -\frac{\ddot{f}}{f} - \frac{\dot{f}^2}{f^2} $ which is in agreement with my previous result because (given $R^l_{ijk} = \frac{\partial}{\partial x^j} \Gamma^l_{ik} - \frac{\partial}{\partial x^k} \Gamma^l_{ij} + \Gamma^s_{ik}\Gamma^l_{sj} - \Gamma^s_{ij}\Gamma^l_{sk}$) $R^x_{uxu}= - \frac {d}{du}(\frac{\dot{f}}{f})$

Comment: The problem may arise from the fact that the expression you've quoted for the Christoffel symbols of the second kind is incorrect. It should be

$$
\Gamma^{k}_{li} = \frac{1}{2}g^{km}\left(\frac{\partial g_{ml}}{\partial q^{i}} + \frac{\partial g_{mi}}{\partial q^{l}} - \frac{\partial g_{li}}{\partial q^{m}}\right) \,.
$$

I am certain Schutz's book gives the correct expression. The answers there are correct. I did the calculation a few years ago.

Comment: @Physics_Et_Al:  I think the OP's expression is equivalent to yours under relabeling of indices, except for the fact that it should be $\Gamma^m {}_{li}$ on the left-hand side of the OP's equation.

Comment: @Michael Seifert, on a second look I thought too and posted a comment in that regard but deleted it because I thought there was problem with signs but a third look seems to indicate that there isn’t. All that has to be done is to relabel the index $m$ on the right-hand side. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: @G.Tos, apologies. I think you might be correct. I have looked at my copy of Schutz’s book and found that beside the equations you ask about I have written “error?”  in regard to the Christoffel symbols you are concerned about. I won’t be able to dig out my notes tonight or do the calculation right now to confirm your answer though. Sorry.

Comment: @Physics_Et_Al thank you anyway. If you give a a look to Schutz's book the page is 211 (second edition, just before eq. 9.32). I really don't understand how he calculates the Christoffel's symbols; my way may be wrong.

Comment: @G.Tos, I have the first edition of the book and remember checking a copy of the second edition in a library to see if there a correction had been made and it hadn’t. So I actually think there is a misprint in both editions.